# Require wp-load.php returns error now without code change, the path worked until now

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress functions inside sub-directory of my Wordpress site.
I am including the `wp-load.php` using the following code:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

It was working fine until day before yesterday. No change was made in the program or location of `wp-load.php` as the Wordpress site is also working fine. It has started to generate error

```
require(/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/mysite/public_html/processes/forms/chklogin.php on line 3
```

The `wp-load.php` file is right there as it was before in the site root. There is no change in `.htaccess` too.

What is going on ?

Comment: `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php'` to see whats there?

Comment: echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; shows correct path to wordpress root which is also site root

Comment: had you changed the file permissions of wp-load.php ??

Comment: @HritikPandey : No, from the other php files in the same folder which include wp-load.php are working fine. Including or Requiring it from sub-folder fail to include it.